# How to display text in shortform while selecting from a column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, display, workbench

Display text as BE instead of Backend while selecting department from employee table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    case department
        when 'Backend' then 'BE'
        else department
    end as department
from
    employee
;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.